# Kotlin Multiplatform Android module only has access to Android API 1

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform

I'm working on a multiplatform project in Kotlin that has an Android module.

In one of my files, I have the code:

```
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
```

Which gets the following compiler error:

```
Unresolved reference: MATCH_PARENT
```

All of the references to anything beyond Android API level 1 get a similar compiler error, but not any references that are available in Android API level 1.

Android Studio recognizes all of the references made, and code completion is working on them just fine.  Only when I compile do these errors show up.

My gradle file looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
        classpath "digital.wup:android-maven-publish:3.1.1"
        classpath 'com.jfrog.bintray.gradle:gradle-bintray-plugin:1.8.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${rootProject.kotlinVersion}"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.dokka:dokka-android-gradle-plugin:${rootProject.dokkaVersion}"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-platform-android'
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.dokka-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        warning('InvalidPackage', 'NewApi')
    }
}

repositories {
    google()
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url "https://maven.google.com"
    }
}

dependencies {
    def compatVersion = '27.1.1'

    androidTestImplementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:${compatVersion}"
//    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:${rootProject.kotlinVersion}"


    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    implementation "com.lightningkite.kotlinx:jvm:${rootProject.libraryVersion}"
    implementation "com.github.bigfishcat.android:svg-android:2.0.8"
    expectedBy project(':common')

    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${compatVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${compatVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:${compatVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${compatVersion}"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:${compatVersion}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, whatever the issue was internally, it was actually triggered by this library in my `build.gradle` file:

```
implementation "com.github.bigfishcat.android:svg-android:2.0.8"
```

How a library cause this, I do not know.  Everything builds fine now though.

Answer (score -1):

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

**apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'**

**apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'**

android {

```
compileSdkVersion 26

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.admin.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

}

dependencies {

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
```

}

my android studio version is 3.1.1
wroking properly

remove all kotlin library from your gradle
and put

implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions

and in top level gradle bulid.gradle(your_app_name) put

buildscript {

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.30'
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

}

Comment: This is not for Kotlin Multiplatform, which uses the `kotlin-platform-android` plugin, and thus does not answer the question.